# How to filter the information in a page?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/31121-magix_movie_edit_pro_2014_premium"
pageUrl = urllib.urlopen(url)
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageUrl)

for a in  soup.select("div.downloadLink a[href]"):
    print "downloadlink: "+a["href"]

for b in soup.select("h1#articleTitle"):
    print b

for c in soup.select("table.detailsTable"):
    print c
```

What I want is the application name,date updated,developer and download link.
When I tried to run it, the output will be all the things inside each tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that gets what you want:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/31121-magix_movie_edit_pro_2014_premium"
pageUrl = urllib.urlopen(url)
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageUrl)

for a in  soup.select("div.downloadLink a[href]"):
    print "downloadlink: " + "?" + a["href"].split("?")[1].split(",")[0]

for b in soup.select("h1#articleTitle"):
    print b.contents[0].strip()

for c in soup.findAll("th"):
    if c.text == "Date Updated:":
        print c.parent.td.text
    elif c.text == "Developer:":
        print c.parent.td.text
```

But you can't download the file with that URL. You will need to check JavaScript source files to see what `javascript:checkDownload()` does to get the actual file location.

Comment: where can I check the javascript source file? Sorry for asking this question because I never face this kind of thing before this.

Comment: If you are using chrome press F12. Go to resources tab and press ctrl+f. Search for checkDownload fucntion. Check files that have this function. 
If you are using firefox. Install firebug. Press F12. Go to Script tab. Press ctrl+f. Search for checkDownload fucntion. Check files that have this function.